# Maximise minimized outlook from system tray

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, shortcuts, notification-area

If outlook 2010 is minimized to system tray, is there any shortcut key for maximizing or switching to outlook from system tray. WIN XP

Answer (score 2):

As far as I could find in the Outlook help - no (I checked `outlook-2007`, but it is probably the same in that aspect).

If you **bind** a keyboard shortcut to launching outlook (i.e. to its shortcut) you can get almost the desired effect. Outlook will start, but identify that an instance is already running and will just restore it. It is slower than actually restoring outlook, but not that much.

Comment: for me it is not working :(

Comment: Try running outlook (start menu, quick launch etc.) without binding it first. See if that works. If not, it is very strange as it works for me.

Comment: First time it is working. Once it is minimized to system tray, the shortcut seems not working :(

Comment: Seems like a keyboard bind does not work if the shortcut is in the `Quick Launch` area. However - if the shortcut is in the `Start Menu` - it works for me fine. I did the binding to `Ctrl+Alt+1`

Comment: it worked for first time but not after that :(

Comment: Very weird. Try using http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm to bind the hotkey - maybe this will help.
B.T.W., Which `Windows` version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I place the outlook as the top of the windows start menu. Then when I press the windows key, I will press E (which stands for e-mail client).

Answer (score 0):

Install AutoHotkey and edit it's script file, add this line for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to achieve your desired effect:
`^!O::Run, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\OUTLOOK.EXE" /recycle`